# How to create docker compose for hybris commerce

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sap-commerce-cloud

I would like to run hybris with the docker.

I am trying to create a docker to run hybris.

Can anyone help me with this?

This is my code:

UPDATE Question:

When I enter the container (ubuntu) and try to build hybris, there is always an error.

I created the docker-compose and the dockerfile. However, when I run ant clean all in the container the build always fails.

[![![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - //C/dockerVolumes/db_local_hybris:/var/lib/mysql
    container_name: mysql_hybris
    hostname: mysql_hybris
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=***
      - MYSQL_USER=***
  hybris:
    image: miltex/jdk:hybrisDevs
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: hybris_dev
    hostname: hybris_dev
    ports:
      - "8009:8009"
      - "8010:8010"
      - "9001:9001"
      - "9002:9002"
      - "1099:1099"
    tty: true
    links:
      - db

Dockerfile
FROM miltex/jdk:1.8

#update
RUN apt-get update

## Run Initial Ant ##
RUN mkdir -p /app/hybris_dev
COPY ./hybris/HYBRISCOMM6700P_10-80003492.ZIP /app/hybris_dev/ 
RUN cd /app/hybris_dev && unzip HYBRISCOMM6700P_10-80003492.ZIP
#COPY ./bin/hybris-wrapper.sh /app/hybris_dev/hybris/bin/platform/
RUN mkdir /app/hybris_dev/hybris/bin/custom
COPY ./src/custom /app/hybris_dev/hybris/bin/custom
RUN cd /app/hybris_dev/installer && rm -R recipes
RUN mkdir /app/hybris_dev/installer/recipes
COPY ./src/custom/recipes /app/hybris_dev/installer/recipes

#CMD /app/hybris_dev/intaller/install.sh -r local setup ; /app/hybris_dev/hybris/bin/custom/platform/setantenv.sh ; ant clean all

## Copy hybris-wrapper to configure template properties at runtime ##
COPY ./bin/hybris-wrapper.sh /hybris-wrapper.sh

## Expose AJP S-AJP HTTP HTTPS RMI ports ##
EXPOSE 8009 8010 9001 9002 1099

RUN chmod -R 777 /app

#RUN chmod +x /hybris-wrapper.sh
# Run Hybris server
#ENTRYPOINT ["/hybris-wrapper.sh"]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoK3E.png
```

Comment: Mysql runs successfully. However, an error occurs in debian.

Comment: That sounds like you're looking for a Dockerfile to build a custom image.  Trying to bind-mount and install an entire application when the container starts up isn't typical best practice.

Comment: What would be good practice in this case?

Comment: Build the application into an image.  Run it without any `volumes:`, `command:`, `container_name`, `hostname:`, or `links:` options.

Comment: I always have to mount the container with the updated source code customizations.

Comment: In this case, when I create the application the source code is obtained from the updated git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was the image I was using before. Now this dockerhub [miltex:jdk:1.8](https://cloud.docker.com/repository/docker/miltex/jdk) image is working perfectly.